# Python/ Binary table from list of words

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, binary

I would like to create a binary table from a list of words that are in a text file. (in Python)
I collected all of the words from different tweets and add them to a dictionary.(which is represented by Word1 Word2 Word3... here and have all)

So, in my exemple all of the words of the tweet1 of present in my dictionary. In the second tweet, only the third word of the tweet is present in my dictionary.

```
        Word1 Word2 Word3 ...
Tweet1    1     1     1
Tweet2    0     0     1
Tweet3    0     0     0
```

The different words collected are in a text file like that :

```
April
Today
I'm
going
to
add
BLOOD
ALL
OVER
YOUR
HANDS
```

EDIT :
It works well when I use the tweet directly in the script. However, when i put exactly the same tweet in a file I have an error.

```
def tabBinaire():
with open("data", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        defi = cool.DataFrame(line)
        print(defi)
        cv = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r'\w{1,}')
        df1 = cv.fit_transform(defi['tweet'])
        output = cool.DataFrame(df1.todense(), columns=cv.get_feature_names())
        print(output)
```

My file:

```
{'tweet': ['how happy am i today','why is it not raining today','why is sky blue']}
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py2.py", line 42, in <module>
    tabBinaire();
  File "py2.py", line 33, in tabBinaire
    defi = cool.DataFrame(line)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 404, in __init__
    raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide an expected output as well. How do you expect the binary table to look like? @Ravure

Comment: As in my example with Word1 Word2 Word3 ... That's what I'm looking for

Comment: did you check CountVectorizer from sklearn? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimal example of what you want to do:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
df = pd.DataFrame({'tweet': ['how happy am i today','why is it not raining today','why is sky blue']})

# initialise vectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r'\w{1,}')

# apply countvec
df1 = cv.fit_transform(df['tweet'])

# create output 
output = pd.DataFrame(df1.todense(), columns=cv.get_feature_names())

print(output)
```

[image]